# TYPO3 - direct_mail - fe_user - unsubscribe

Tags: typo3, newsletter, sr-feuser-registration

In 8 / 9 LTS, how to unsubscribe fe_user from from direct_mail newsletter? What i want to achieve:

1. User clicks "unsubscribe" link in newsletter
2. User should be auto-logged-in / authenticated (SYS_AUTH_CODE)
3. User should either be redirected to edit form, or else the "module_sys_dmail" flag should be deactivated (without edit form)
4. User (fe_user) itself must not be deleted or set hidden

Can this behaviour been achieved by just using TER extensions (direct_mail + ???) or do i have to write my own extension for this?

Comment: EXT:direct_mail doesn't offer any subscription/unsubscription functionality. Did you already have a look at some extension in TER?

Comment: Yes, did. But couldn‘t figure out without trying. Perhaps EXT:sr_feuser_register does. I did lots with direct_mail, but always with tt-address, not fe_user...